# How to query in data set of Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data structure looks like:

```
{
    "node_1" : {
        "node_2": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "catCode": 1,
                "catName": "cat name",
                "title": "Title 1",
                "description": "description 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "catCode": 2,
                "catName": "cat name",
                "title": "Title 2",
                "description": "description 2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "catCode": 2,
                "catName": "cat name",
                "title": "Title 3",
                "description": "description 3"
            }
        ]
    } 
}
```

1. How can I query in it in a way that I only get list of `title`s? something like: `["Title 1","Title 2","Title 3"]`
2. How can I query in it in a way that I get list of `title`s that their `"catCode": 2`? something like: `["Title 2","Title 3"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Database always returns complete nodes. So there is no single read operation that returns just the `title` nodes from under `node_2`.

That means that there is also no query that can return just the titles for items with `catCode == 2`. But you can get the entire nodes and then print just the titles with:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("node_1/node_2");
Query items = ref.orderByChild("catCode").equalTo(2);
items.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      Log.i(TAG, itemSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class));
    }
  }

  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is not interesting to me because this a Book actually, `title` is the title of each chapter and `description` is content of that chapter. Does your sample code means the whole Book gets loaded into memory of device?

Comment: Yes, as said: the Firebase Database always returns complete nodes. If you want just the title and not the other properties, you should store the titles in a separate list.